# startx doesn't boot, raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, putty

I've had this issue with multiple computers and multiple pi's.
When I try and run startx the GUI doesn't boot.

I've read a lot of other forums about this but it didn't really solve my problem. The pi tries to launch it but the process just doesn't complete.

I feel like something is blocking it from launching the GUI, or I'm missing a package of some kind.

I can get startx to launch fine when I'm not using a serial connection (hdmi/monitor/keyboard instead of puTTY).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I haven't used PuTTY in a long time but whenever I want UI via SSH I use the `-X` flag. I'm not sure if PuTTY supports this. Remote desktop connection should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah last time I just used RDC but I find it so weird how it doesn't boot properly when you use the startx command from the terminal. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Btw I don't think it's weird. If you start a terminal session and try to launch the window manager you are basically trying to use a completely different type of session. You either initialize the session connection to use GUI or you stick to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To see output on your Windows machine, you need an X-Server. A commonly used X-Server for Windows is [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/xmingnotes)

You'll also have to configure X11 forwarding in Putty.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I didn't know that existed